# Android Track Positions in a custom ListView without itemclicklistener

Tags: android, android-listview, position, baseadapter

I have a `ListView` with custom list items using a `BaseAdapter` and `ViewHolder`. Each list item has two `Buttons`, and a `TextView`. I have set click listeners for both buttons. Now the `onItemClickEvent` for the `ListView` does not work. I think the buttons consume the click event or something similar.

I can find out which button was clicked, but I can't get the row position,
as the `ViewHolder` is recycled. I cant do this without ViewHolder` as there is high possibility of the number of list items can  become very large.

How can i get the row position when a button is clicked .

I tried this after doing some googling , But still there is no change in the out come.
Could someone give any suggestions.

Below is my ListItem Layout and BaseAdapter

ListItem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

BaseAdapter

```
class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        LayoutInflater li;
        Context context;


        public MyBaseAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context=context;
            li=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO u-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            final ViewHolder holder;


            if(convertView==null)
            {
                holder=new ViewHolder();

                convertView=li.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent,false);
                holder.iv1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                ImageView iv=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                iv.setTag(position);
                holder.iv2=iv;


                holder.tv1=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.pos=position;

                holder.iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IV1 "+holder.pos, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
                    }
                });

                holder.iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        int x=(int) v.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IV2 "+x, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.tv1.setText("LIST ITEM "+position);
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView tv1;
            ImageView iv1,iv2;
            int pos;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What about to set position tag on button?

Comment: @ChkOnDanger i aldded the code that i used , it uses the tag as u suggested for the second imageview, could u check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set position every time.

```
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView=li.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent,false);
        holder.iv1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.iv2 =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        holder.iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // get position from tag.
                int selection = (int) v.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "IV1 "+selection,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ...
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // set position.
    holder.v1.setTag(position);
    ...
```

Comment: @ChkOnDanger It works now , it makes sense to write it every time and not only when the ui is inflated. Thanks for the help. i will accept this answer